# AWS Lambda not finding Shared Object File in Layer

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver, shared-libraries

I'm trying to create a Lambda function that runs Selenium tests in Java as part of a CI/CD pipeline in AWS. However, after the function installs Chromedriver, it fails because a .so file that Chromedriver requires is missing:

```
/tmp/chrome_driver7811961600494562711/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libglib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have read that you can include native libraries via Software Layers in Lambda, and I understand that you have to compile it in an Amazon Linux environment, as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-linux-binary-package/).

However, after zipping the file, and creating my layer, it's still not picking up the library, and giving the same error. I've also tried putting it in various directories in the zip file, like `/opt`, `/opt/lib`, and also setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable in the function, but still no luck. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you should place the shared library in `/lib64/` .Plus not sure how you are deploying your lambda, you can simply create a docker image that you can test locally using [java lambda docker image](https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/java). Must faster and fully testable locally.

Comment: `/lib64` didn't work either. I'm deploying it through the AWS console. I just don't understand why there are so many different answers to this question and none of them seem to work...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, I finally figured it out. After reading through more of the documentation, I found 2 key points:

First, from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html, the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by default is set to:

`/lib64:/usr/lib64:$LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR:$LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR/lib:$LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT:$LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT/lib:/opt/lib`

And second, from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path :

> Layers are extracted to the `/opt` directory in the function execution environment.

So putting these 2 facts together, I reasoned that if I put the dependencies in `/lib` within the layer, they will end up in `/opt/lib`, which is in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and voila - it worked.

Comment: I just want to clarify because I've been banging my head on this for a while:
You literally move the .so files to a folder called lib and zip it up and it works? I swear I tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes. A few things to check: Make sure that you aren't overriding LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your environment variables. Chances are there are more than 1 dependencies that are missing, so make sure the error isn't complaining about a different one. Make sure you're using the 64-bit versions instead of the 32 one, or you will get a similar looking error - be sure you expand it to read the full text of the error.

Comment: What base os did you assume Amazon Linux uses? CentOS?

Comment: @Axl Amazon Linux is its own OS. But when you type `cat /etc/*release` it says `ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"`, so I guess it's kind of based on it. But if you're asking how I got the required libs, I ran a docker image of Amazon Linux 2 locally and grabbed them from there after installing them with yum.

Comment: I had the same issue, and needed to change the lambda function runtime from "Runtime.DOTNET_CORE_3_1" to "Runtime.PROVIDED".

I couldn't find official documentation about which libraries is provided in the different runtimes. But found, that according to the following reddit thread libglib.so.1 is missing in runtimes

https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/bxzzov/node_10_lambda_runtime_does_not_match_the/

Comment: Hi, I was wondering where I would find the libglib-2.0.so.0 file i need to add to the layer?

Comment: @M.Phys Basically you need to build a docker image with Amazon Linux 2, log into the instance then install the libraries you need using yum, then copy them into your local machine from the docker instance.

Comment: I managed to get chomedriver and headless chromium working with python 3.7 lambda but this link was helpful in getting there! Cheers

Comment: @M.Phys Glad to help! You could always upvote the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem while trying to use pysodium, which relies on finding libsodium at runtime.

Even though libsodium was there in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, this line was still failing:

```py
sodium = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library('sodium') or ctypes.util.find_library('libsodium'))
```

I ended up explicitly loading the library from the place where I'd put it (as a layer):

```py
sodium = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(
    ctypes.util.find_library('sodium')
    or ctypes.util.find_library('libsodium')
    or "/opt/lib/libsodium.so"  # layers are deployed here
)
```